# output hive results in parquet format files

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

Can you export a hive query result into parquet file formats? I can export results as a tsv like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/home/user/events'
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '\t'
```

but how do I tell it to do it in parquet format?

Answer (score 8):

insert overwrite directory 'EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY' STORED AS PARQUET select * from SOURCE_TABLE_NAME;

Answer (score 1):

Use the below approach

> create table parque_table (
>
> ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' STORED AS
>   INPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat"
>             OUTPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat" LOCATION '${hiveconf:hive_location}';
>
> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE parque_table  select from othertable

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create one table with the schema of your results in hive **stored as parquet**. After getting the results you can export them into the parquet file format table like this

```
insert into table parquet_file_table_name select * from table_name_containing_results
```

For more information you can refer to the below link

https://acadgild.com/blog/parquet-file-format-hadoop/